# How to scroll the browser window

Tags: c#, jquery

I am using C# code and displayed the Page and when i click on the link button on the top of the page then the page should scroll to the bottom of the page because the related content will be on the bottom of the page.

How can i achieve this

can u give me the solution for this scenario either programatically in c# or in jquery

Thanks in advance
Vara Prasad.M

Comment: Not use about jQuery, but in javascript you can do `window.scrollBy(x,y)` or `window.scroll(x,y)`.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a [nice plugin](http://flesler.blogspot.com/2007/10/jqueryscrollto.html) that allows you to easily scroll to any part of the document.